# HashMap inside struct error: cannot move out of xxx which is behind a shared reference

Tags: rust

I have the following Rust structure which has a `HashMap` to children structures.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node {
    children: HashMap<i32, Node>,
}

impl Node {
    fn no_children(&self) -> usize {
        if self.children.is_empty() {
            1
        } else {
            1 + self
                .children
                .into_iter()
                .map(|(_, child)| child.no_children())
                .sum::<usize>()
        }
    }
}
```

I implemented `no_children(&self)` to find the total number of nodes. However, under `self.children`, Rust highlights an error because:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.children` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/lib.rs:13:17
   |
13 |               1 + self
   |  _________________^
14 | |                 .children
   | |_________________________^ move occurs because `self.children` has type `std::collections::HashMap<i32, Node>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I am not sure what is missing. I have tried adding `&self.children...` but still got the same error.

Comment: As a side note, your `no_immediate_children` counts **all** the children recursively, not just the immediate ones…

Comment: @Jmb thanks, I have edited that in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `.into_iter(self)` needs to take ownership of the `HashMap`, but in `no_immediate_children(&self)` the `HashMap` is behind a reference -> i.e. `&self` instead of `self`;

You can work around that in two ways, depending on what you want to achieve:

1. If you want to consume the elements of the hash map and leave it empty after the method invocation:

   - Change the receiver to `&mut self`
   - Use `.drain()` instead of `.into_iter()`:

     ```
     self.children.drain().map(|(_, mut v)| v.no_immediate_children()).sum::<usize>() + 1
     ```
2. If you just want to get the sum, but do not want to modify the `HashMap`:

   - Use `.iter()` instead of `.into_iter()`:

     ```
     self.children.iter().map(|(_k, v)| v.no_immediate_children()).sum::<usize>() + 1
     ```
3. You want to consume the whole `Node` chain:

   - Change the method signature to `fn no_immediate_children(self)` and use `.into_iter()` as it is.